# Update request passes but doesn't update token react-oidc-context

Tags: reactjs, web, token

Before the token expire, there is an automatic request to update it, the request goes well, but does not update the token, and subsequent requests fail. I have to refresh the page to refresh the tokens

There was a chance to use revokeTokens but there is no such request on the backend and for some reason I can't use it.
I expect the token refresh to happen in the background so that I don't have to reload the page

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.